# How make a loop with variable

Tags: r

Currently , I have 4 lines for a simple ifelse on 4 columns. I'm pretty new in R, how can I do this in a single line ?
Thank you ! :)

I tried to do that in function like

```r
my_function <- function(var) {
datamart_apprentissage  <- mutate(datamart_apprentissage, var= ifelse(is.na(var), 0, 1))
}

my_function("VIE_OB3_1")
my_function("VIE_OB3_2")
my_function("VIE_OB3_3")
my_function("VIE_OB3_4")
```

but didnt work

```r
datamart_apprentissage  <- mutate(datamart_apprentissage, VIE_OB3_1 = ifelse(is.na(VIE_OB3_1), 0, 1))
datamart_apprentissage  <- mutate(datamart_apprentissage, VIE_OB3_2 = ifelse(is.na(VIE_OB3_2), 0, 1))
datamart_apprentissage  <- mutate(datamart_apprentissage, VIE_OB3_3 = ifelse(is.na(VIE_OB3_3), 0, 1))
datamart_apprentissage  <- mutate(datamart_apprentissage, VIE_OB3_4 = ifelse(is.na(VIE_OB3_4), 0, 1))
```

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you create a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we can work with?

Comment: Hello ! For general *loop* purposes, I would advise you to learn about `sapply()` and `lapply()` functions. You can  get info about them by typing `help("sapply")` in the R terminal. 
Also, R supports more basic functions (`for()` and `while()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`, to customize which column are transformed use the .vars argument in `mutate_at` :

```r
library("dplyr", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
datamart_apprentissage <- matrix(sample(x = c(NA, 2:3), size = 5*4, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4)
datamart_apprentissage <- as_tibble(datamart_apprentissage )
#> Warning: `as_tibble.matrix()` requires a matrix with column names or a `.name_repair` argument. Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
#> This warning is displayed once per session.
names(datamart_apprentissage) <- paste0("VIE_OB3_", 1:4)

# --- What you wanna do
datamart_apprentissage %>% 
        mutate_at(.vars = paste0("VIE_OB3_", 1:4), .funs = function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   VIE_OB3_1 VIE_OB3_2 VIE_OB3_3 VIE_OB3_4
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1         0         1         1         1
#> 2         1         0         1         1
#> 3         1         1         0         0
#> 4         0         1         0         1
#> 5         1         1         0         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use column-wise apply:

```
# Some data
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,4), b = c(NA,NA,7,8))

# Function for replacing NA with value
myfun <- function(col) {
  out <- ifelse(is.na(col), 0, 1)
  return(out)
}

# Applying function column-wise (option = 2)
apply(df, 2, function(col) myfun(col))

# As oneliner
apply(df, 2, function(col) ifelse(is.na(col), 0, 1))
```

Comment: Or `df[, c("c", "e")] <- as.integer(!is.na(df[, c("c", "e")]))`

Comment: Thanks for you answer,
If I want do this to specifics colums like
```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,4), b = c(NA,NA,7,8)), d(NA,NA,7,8)),e(NA,NA,7,8))
```
and I want apply only on c and e colums, how can I do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` which will keep the `dataframe` structure. Below is an exemple where you can replace the `NA` with `"VALUE"`

You can replace the `function(x)ifelse` by your own function (I have no experience with `mutate` so I can't help with that.

Also, you can select only specific rows/columns using `[row,column]`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,NA,NA,5),b=c(NA,7,8,NA,10),c=c(NA,7,8,NA,10),d=c(NA,7,8,NA,10),e=c(NA,7,8,NA,10))
df
df[,c(1,2)] <- sapply(df[,c(1,2)],function(x)ifelse(is.na(x),"VALUE",x))
df
```